# How to call a function from my discord bot python file which is already running from another file

Tags: python, pycord

**What i want is when i run xyz.py it should print "works" in terminal where bot.py is running**

So i want to call a function in my discord bot python file which is already running from another python file :
In bot.py:

```
async def call_1():
print("works")
```

In xyz.py:

```
from bot import call_1
call_1()
```

Now bot.py is running and then I run xyz.py.

What happens is xyz.py will run the bot again

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `call_1()` function as an async function.
In order to execute it, you have to call it using the asyncio module https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/asyncio.html :

In your **xyz.py** file:

```
import asyncio
from bot import call_1

asyncio.run(call_1())
```

In your **bot.py** file:

```
async def call_1():
    print("works")

def main():
    #Do some stuff
    while True:
         pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: it prints "works"  in terminal where xyz.py is running. 
I want it to print "works" in terminal where bot.py is running from xyz.py
i am trying to send a message by calling a function in bot.py from xyz.py